# Trying to unpickle a list of tuples then for loop through the list to display all tuples in a row highscore board Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

New to coding and only been studying Python for a month.

Im unpickling a file which contains a list of tuples storing the users name, the score and the time they completed the test. The list holds up to 10 tuples but when I unpickle and use this for loop I can only get one tuple to display. I want it to display them all in a row. Its probably something small but Im at a blank and can't figure it out, so hoping someone can help.

Currently this is how it looks when run:

```
_______HighScore Board_______
NAME    SCORE   TIME OF ENTRY
bill 28.02 03:27PM 23-November-2012
```

It does not display any of the other saved scores, so do I need to create another loop to keep running through the list and printing the tuples?

The snippet of code is as follows:

thanks in advance

Comment: You should also show the code where the object is pickled.  Perhaps you're not pickling the entire object correctly.

Comment: Agree with @mgilson - check everything is there by doing `print scores`

Comment: Thanks guys, added the Pickle section. Im sure I must be doing something really dumb

Comment: before "for entry in scores:" what does len(scores) output?

Comment: 0... so it must be something to do with me not pickling or populating the list correctly. I will add the code on how the list is populated before pickling. Is it worth me clearing the .dat file?

Comment: Assuming SCOREBOARD_FILE is what you call the .dat file, there's no need to clean it, but your comment suggests that you don't realize that it is overwritten (and the previous contents thrown away) every time you open it.

Comment: Ah thank you, I thought I was told by someone that pickling kept adding to the file. So basically I need to unpickle the file then put the unpickled tuples into the empty list along with any new entry tuples, then repickle. This way it should always keep all the scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment "Could it be overwriting the pickled list rather than adding to it?" is correct. It cannot do anything else, if you think about it:

open (..., 'w') will open a file for writing, truncating it to length 0 if it already exists. In other words, the previous contents are discarded.

pickle will create a data packet which you can store or pass over the network. In this case, you write it to the opened and truncated file. This file then contains only the thing you just pickled.

When retrieving the contents, it will therefore only see the last thing you put in, because you erased the rest when you opened the file.

There are two things you can do. If you open the file for append ('ab' instead of 'wb'), you can write several pickled things after each other. You should also be able to read them after each other. I don't recommend this, though, unless the file is intended to be so large that you don't want to load it all into memory.

Normally, when adding something to the board you will need to read the current board, add an item to the list, and write the resulting board back to the file (intentionally overwriting the old board).